# Need USB 2.0 header on USB 3.0 motherboard

Tags: usb, usb-3, adapter, headers, usb-2

I have a PC that only has 1 USB 3.0 header on the motherboard. I'm needing to plug in the Bluetooth cable from my WiFi card to a USB 2.0 header.

My only real option seems to be using a right angle 3.0 header adapter (because the existing cable is right angle and has no clearance for the drive cage), a USB 3.0 header splitter cable and a USB 3.0 header to USB 2.0 adapter.

This is allot of spaghetti in my case and is a more complicated solution than I'd like.

Ideally I'd want USB 3.0 header splitter that has 1 USB 3.0 female header and one USB 2.0 header.

I would consider a USB 2.0 PCI-e expansion card but I only have 1 port that the WiFi card is using.

I want an internal solution so USB A to USB 2.0 header adapters are not ideal.

Comment: I have never seen a 2-1 header adapter. Mixing USB 2 and USB 3.2 Gen 2 signals makes my spider senses go off due to the differences in power. My suggestion, convert the header into a normal Type-A or Type-B plug and route it outside your case and plug it into the USB 3.2 Gen 1 port